# Display category names instead of ids

Tags: magento-1.9, category, database, drop-downs

We are fetching information from database and displaying category ids, but we want to display category names instead of ids.

[image]

now in 2nd  dropdown box, instead of "category id" , we want to display  category names.

```
foreach ($categories as $category){
$cat_id = $category["category_id"];
```

**full phtml**

```
public function getOptions()
    {
       $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$query = 'SELECT category_id, category_name FROM ' . $resource->getTableName('outthink_advance_brand_category');

$categories = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

$brandsArr = array();

$brandSelect = '<select id="brand_select">';
$brandSelect .= '<option value="">My Brand</option>';
foreach ($categories as $category){
$cat_id = $category["category_id"];

$brandSelect .= "<option value='".$category["category_id"]."'>".$category["category_name"]."</option>";

$query = 'SELECT `outthink_advance_brand`.brand_id, `outthink_advance_brand`.originalcategory_id FROM `outthink_advance_brand` ';
$query .= ' inner join `outthink_advance_brand_category_item` on
(`outthink_advance_brand`.brand_id = `outthink_advance_brand_category_item`.brand_id )';
$query .= ' where `outthink_advance_brand_category_item`.category_id = '.$cat_id;

$brands = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

$bArr = array();

foreach ($brands as $brand){
$bArr[$brand["brand_id"]] = $brand["originalcategory_id"];
}
$brandsArr[$cat_id] = $bArr;
}
$brandSelect .= '</select>';

return $brandSelect.'<select id="model_select"><option value="">My Model</option></select>';

    }
    public function getbrandsArr()
    {
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$query = 'SELECT category_id, category_name FROM ' . $resource->getTableName('outthink_advance_brand_category');

$categories = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

$brandsArr = array();

$brandSelect = '<select id="brand_select">';
$brandSelect .= '<option value="">My Brand</option>';
foreach ($categories as $category){
$cat_id = $category["category_id"];

$brandSelect .= "<option value='".$category["category_id"]."'>".$category["category_name"]."</option>";

$query = 'SELECT `outthink_advance_brand`.brand_id, `outthink_advance_brand`.originalcategory_id FROM `outthink_advance_brand` ';
$query .= ' inner join `outthink_advance_brand_category_item` on
(`outthink_advance_brand`.brand_id = `outthink_advance_brand_category_item`.brand_id )';
$query .= ' where `outthink_advance_brand_category_item`.category_id = '.$cat_id;

$brands = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

$bArr = array();

foreach ($brands as $brand){
$bArr[$brand["brand_id"]] = $brand["originalcategory_id"];
}
$brandsArr[$cat_id] = $bArr;
}
     return $brandsArr;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using the second column of your MySQL request?

Try this:

```
foreach ($categories as $category){
    $cat_id = $category["category_id"];
    $cat_name = $category["category_name"]; //HERE IS WHAT YOU WANT
}
```

Let me know..

Comment: sorry, it did't worked for me , please check [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/customized-mobile-cases)

Comment: @BabyinMagento I changed my answer, please give this code a try and let me know!

Comment: i am checking now

Comment: sorry , it didt worked for me, i added your code like this : http://pastebin.com/q9jVUqar

Comment: @BabyinMagento Could you please post a print of a line of the database? So I can see the data the db contains and build a query around it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for support, we resolved issue , can you please help [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127462/replace-product-image-by-image-uploaded-through-custom-options)